# Is it possible to change/modify predefined route in Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

you know, Laravel Passport have predefined routes as folllow:

```
php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                     | Name | Action                                      | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                       |      | Closure                                     | web          |
|        | POST     | oauth/authorize                         |      | ...\ApproveAuthorizationController@approve  | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/authorize                         |      | ...\AuthorizationController@authorize       | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/authorize                         |      | ...\DenyAuthorizationController@deny        | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/clients                           |      | ...\ClientController@forUser                | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/clients                           |      | ...\ClientController@store                  | web,auth     |
|        | PUT      | oauth/clients/{client_id}               |      | ...\ClientController@update                 | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/clients/{client_id}               |      | ...\ClientController@destroy                | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/personal-access-tokens            |      | ...\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/personal-access-tokens            |      | ...\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id} |      | ...\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/scopes                            |      | ...\ScopeController@all                     | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token                             |      | ...\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh                     |      | ...\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/tokens                            |      | ...\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                 |      | ...\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web,auth     |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Is it possible to modify that route?
e.g. `oauth/authorize` become `api/v1/oauth/authorize`

if yes, how?

I've been searching for answer quite sometime...

Comment: Can you post where you register the laravel passport routes.

Comment: Which registration that you refer to? i don't remember that i register any route during Passport installation

Comment: @Remul `Passport::routes();` in `AuthServiceProvider@boot` for laravel8.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can declare your own routes in `Passport::routes()` method.

Include this inside the `boot()` method of your `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider` file.

**app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**

```php
public function boot()
{
    Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'api/v1/oauth']);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems like the `routes` method has been removed (Passport 11.x).

In order to do this now, you would need to **publish the Passport configuration file** and set the `path` attribute to the desired value: `api/v1/oauth`.

```bash
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

```php
// config/passport.php

<?php

return [
    ...

    'path' => 'api/v1/oauth',
];
```

I haven't been able to find this information in the documentation. I figured this out by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/src/PassportServiceProvider.php#L56). Here's the link for further reference.